# Struct not assignable?

Tags: c++, struct, assign

I Have a struct:

```
struct Handle 
{
public:
    const unsigned long Id;
    const std::type_index Index;
    Handle() : Id(-1), Index(std::type_index(typeid(Event))){}
    Handle(unsigned long id, std::type_index index) : Id(id), Index(index) {}
};
```

but when I try to assign it to a variable I get

> Error 10  error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'EventHandler::Handle'

Why ? (I'm using structs because as far as I know they are handled as datatypes and can be returned from functions without being created with new. Is that correct?)

Comment: If your members are `const`, they can't be assigned to like the assignment would do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default assignment operator is not generated for `Handle` because it would be ill-formed. What it does is simply assigns member-wise and that obviously isn't allowed on `const` members.

Instead, don't declare them `const`. If they're not intended to be modified outside of assignment operator, simply put them in `private` section and don't provide interface that would allow modification.